Modified by Column for Changes to Specific Column
I have a document library which users and their managers need to provide acknowledgement on documents. We do this with a date field for both manager and user (Manager Acknowledgement and User Acknowledgement)
However I am wondering if it is possible to create two separate “Modified by” columns that are specific to each acknowledgement column.
Ie: the user input the date in User Acknowledgement and a “Modified by” column would change to the users name.
I am very new to JSON and can’t quite wrap my head around where to start on this one.
Thank you
